# Is it dangerous or safe to use a black/dark cloth cover on a propane tank?

Tags: thermodynamics, visible-light, everyday-life, thermal-radiation, laboratory-safety

Say I have a standard 20lb propane tank.
I want to put a protective cover over it, to shelter it from weather.
Can I use a cover that is black or dark colored? Is that dangerous or will it put me at risk?

Most covers seem to be made from leather, polyester, or cotton/oxford cloth.

[Various](https://www.propane101.com/propanetankcolor.htm) [sites](https://www.lakesgas.com/propane-101/lakes-gas-blog/307-propane-tank-colors.html) will tell you to not paint the *tank* a dark color.
The [NFPA 58 standard](http://www.nfpa.org/assets/files/aboutthecodes/58/58-98-pdf.pdf) seems to suggest painting the tank "a heat-reflective color, such as white".

But that's talking about the tank itself.
If the tank is covered in cloth, will the color make a difference? Would a black cover be safe while out of direct sunlight, but dangerous in direct sun?

I have looked at some [related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78616/) [questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/270/would-wearing-clothing-that-is-black-on-the-inside-and-white-on-the-outside-keep) about cloth color and heat, but I'm not sure if they apply, as a propane tank is different from a human body.

Answer (score 1):

Black absorbs (and emits) radiation more than white or pail colours. It would probably be dangerous to use a black cloth in direct sunlight, but if not in direct sunlight the colour of the cloth will make very little difference, if any.