# Why do people wear black in the Middle East?

Tags: thermodynamics, visible-light, everyday-life, thermal-radiation

I have read various dubious explanations as to why people often wear black in the heat, from cultural to somehow encouraging the evaporation of sweat (unconvincing). So, does anyone know what, if any benefit there is to black clothing in hot dry conditions? It is certainly counterintuitive.

Comment: More on color of clothing: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/270/2451

Answer (score 4):

As it was explained in one of Halliday's books, the reason is that the black dress heats the air inside it up, thus causing a continuous flow of air in between the skin and the dress. The cold air flows in from below, gets heaten up, and gets out from above, providing a continuous ventilation.

Comment: You should give a link. The dress has to be very loose. Look at my answer here with some photos http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1492Would+wearing+clothing+that+is+black+on+the+inside+and+white+on+the+outside+keep+you+cooler%3F